# dracena mass cane is dying... I think? Can anyone give me advice?

Tags: houseplants, watering, repotting, dracaena, corn

I bought this mass cane from Ikea in Sept 2019. Since the day I bought it, the leaves were constantly turning brown. At first, I thought it was because I had given it tap water. Ek. I started over, and store bought distilled water. Ok - still the leaves turned brown. I stopped watering it for almost two months. Still brown leaves that I pruned away. Then I tried repotting it in a bigger pot etc. Now I feel like it's worse than ever. Now full leaves are turning brown and it seems like the stems (not the cane/base) are turning white.

What's wrong with her?? I need help because I can't seem to figure out what's going on... maybe nothing and I'm overreacting?

Not sure - but any advice I would be really appreciative. 
[image]
Thanks!

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an over watering problem. Try to feel if the soil is dry, say a finger deep, before your water it. If it is still wet, don't give it any water yet. And be sure your container has sufficient drainage holes in it. The substrate should never be left soaked, surplus water should be able to get out.

Comment: My moisture meter reads WET. EKKK. What can I do to help dry her out?

Comment: What you can do? Stop watering it for a while ;-) and be sure to have proper drainage. For now just let it dry a bit, repotting when soild and roots are wet is dangerous, the roots could damage and rot.

Answer (score 0):

Excessive water can cause salinity which may be causing the detrimental of leaves . Just add a spoonful of water daily not much not less depending on the size of the plant.You may notice the  changes soon also these plants are indoor plants so they do not require much sunlight !! Hope it helps