# How to save droppy dracena fragans?

Tags: watering

A friend recently gave me this plant to save, it's been over 2 weeks now and I just wanted some suggestions. I plan to repot it due to the roots sticking out the bottom and the soil has TONS of gnats. Any additional suggestions or tips? This is a picture of the plant when I first received it for some reason I can't post 2 pictures but the plant is not dropping to thay extent anymore but it's still not sitting upright like I'd hoped and the soil is no longer wet I've allowed it to dry out. [

[image]

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK8hA.jpg)

Comment: Related  possibly duplicate https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/51345/20139